# Solving 3D-Laplace Equation with boundaries at one single point

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have a question in 3D-Laplace Equation with boundaries at one single point. I tried to solve it using the separation of variables and Green's functions but I am not sure of my answer. I would appreciate your help. Let $\Omega = [0, x_{1}]\times[0, x_{2}]\times[0, x_{3}]$
\begin{align} \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
\Delta U \left( X_{1},X_{2},X_{3} \right) &= 0, \ \mathrm{on} \ \Omega, \\
\left. U \left( X_{1},X_{2},X_{3} \right) \right|_{(X_{1},X_{2},X_{3}) = (x_{1},x_{2},x_{3})} &= 0, \\
\left. \left( \nabla U . \tilde{\textit{n}} \right) \left( X_{1},X_{2},X_{3} \right) \right|_{(X_{1},X_{2},X_{3}) = (x_{1},x_{2},x_{3})} &= 1. 
\end{array} 
\right. 
\end{align}
where $\tilde{\textit{n}} = (\tilde{\textit{n}}_{1},\tilde{\textit{n}}_{2},\tilde{\textit{n}}_{3})$ is the outward unit normal vector to the surface.

Comment: The point $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ is the  angle point for the parallelepiped $\Omega$. What is the normal vector there?

Comment: Dear Andrew, thanks for comment. I got a formula for the normal vector  $\tilde{\textit{n}}$ as it is explained in the answer, where I deduced that $\tilde{\textit{n}}_{2}$ and $\tilde{\textit{n}}_{3}$ have general values but $\tilde{\textit{n}}_{1}$ has a special value as in the answer. I just  want to be sure from solution.

Comment: In over words, you  take $\bar n$ arbitrarily. For any unit vector $\bar n$ there are infinitely many solutions to this problem. In particular, take any harmonic in $\bar \Omega $ function $v$ s.t. $a=\frac{\partial v(P)}{\partial \bar n}\ne0$  at the point $P=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$. Then $u(x)=\frac{u(x)-u(P)}a$ is a solution.

Comment: Just for note, in my solution, $\tilde{n}_{2}$ and $\tilde{n}_{3}$ are arbitarary but $\tilde{n}_{1}$ is not arbitrary, where                                                                  
$$\tilde{n}_{1} = \frac{x_{1}}{k \pi \sinh \left(  \sqrt{\left( \frac{k \pi}{x_{1}}\right)^2 + \left( \frac{l \pi}{2 x_{3}}\right)^2} X_{2}\right)}$$                                                                         for $k = 2,4,6,8,...,$ and  $l = 1,5,9,13,...,$.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I think your solution should be $u(x) = \frac{v(x) - v(p)}{a}$ not $u(x) = \frac{u(x) - u(p)}{a}$ because $\frac{\partial}{ \partial \tilde{n}} u(x) = \frac{1}{a}  \frac{\partial}{ \partial \tilde{n}} (v(x) - v(p)) = \frac{1}{a} \frac{\partial v(x)}{ \partial \tilde{n}} = \frac{1}{a} a = 1$ at $x = p$ but $\frac{\partial u(x)}{ \partial \tilde{n}} = \frac{1}{a}  \frac{\partial}{ \partial \tilde{n}} (u(x) - u(p)) = \frac{1}{a} \frac{\partial u(x)}{ \partial \tilde{n}} \Rightarrow  \left(1- \frac{1}{a} \right)  \frac{\partial u(x)}{ \partial \tilde{n}} = 0$ at $x = p$

Comment: Yes, should be $v$ instead of $u$.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried two ways to solve this problem. The first one I used
\begin{align*}
U \left( X_{1},X_{2},X_{3} \right) = \sin \left( \frac{k \pi}{x_{1}} X_{1} \right)  \sinh \left(  \sqrt{\left( \frac{k \pi}{x_{1}}\right)^2 + \left( \frac{l \pi}{2 x_{3}}\right)^2} X_{2}\right)  \sin \left( \frac{l \pi}{2 x_{3}} X_{3}\right),
\end{align*}
if $\tilde{n}_{1} = \frac{x_{1}}{k \pi \sinh \left(  \sqrt{\left( \frac{k \pi}{x_{1}}\right)^2 + \left( \frac{l \pi}{2 x_{3}}\right)^2} X_{2}\right)}$ for $k = 2,4,6,8,...,$ and  $l = 1,5,9,13,...,$ as a solution because it satisfies the 3D-Laplace equation and the Dirichlet boundary condition but I am not sure and confused about satisfying the Neumann boundary condition. I am wondering whether it is correct or not.

The other way to solve this problem is by using the Green's function. Let $G$ be a green function such that
\begin{align*} \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
\triangle_{S} G(W,S)= \delta(W-S), S = (S_{X_{1}},S_{X_{2}},S_{X_{3}}) \in \Omega \\
G(W,S) = 0, S \in \partial \Omega \\
\bigtriangledown_{S} G(W,S).n = c, S \in \partial \Omega   
\end{array} 
\right. 
\end{align*}
for each $W = (X_{1},X_{2},X_{3}) \in \Omega$. Then
\begin{align*}
U(W) &= \int\int\int_{\Omega} \delta(W-S) U(S) d S 
\\
&= \int\int_{\partial \Omega} \frac{\partial G}{\partial n} (W,S) U(S) d S - \int\int\int_{\Omega} \bigtriangledown_{S} G(W,S).\bigtriangledown_{S} U(S) d S
\\
&= \int\int_{\partial \Omega} \underset{=c}{\underbrace{\frac{\partial G}{\partial n} (W,S)}} U(S) d S - \int\int_{\partial \Omega} \underset{=0}{\underbrace{G(W,S)}} \frac{\partial U}{\partial n} d S + \int\int\int_{\Omega}  G(W,S) \underset{=0}{ \underbrace{\triangle_{S} U(S)}} d S 
\\
&= c \left( \int\int_{\partial \Omega \backslash (x_{1},x_{2},x_{3})} U(S) d S + \int\int_{S = (x_{1},x_{2},x_{3})} \underset{=0}{ \underbrace{U(S)}} d S \right) 
\\
&= c \int\int_{\partial \Omega \backslash (x_{1},x_{2},x_{3})} U(S) d S
\end{align*}
Also, I confused about this result because I got nothing improtant from that. I am wondering if there is another assumption to get a very good result.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: For the Laplacian boundary value problem to be well posed in $\Omega$, you must specify boundary data *everywhere* on $\partial \Omega$. Specifying this at just one point on $\partial \Omega$ is not enough